# A float type variable is printed in excessive decimal places when not specified

Tags: python

```
mystring = 'hello'
myfloat = float(10.0)
myint = 20
user = 'Matthew'

if mystring == 'hello':
    print("String: %s + test" % mystring)
if isinstance(myfloat, float) and myfloat == 10.0:
    print('Hi %s Float value:' % user, myfloat)
if isinstance(myint, int) and myint == 20:
    print('Float value is %f & Integer value is' % myfloat, myint)
```

In the illustrated code, the second if statement it checks whether the "myfloat" variable is a float and checks if its equal to that value. Its then printed with the variable value in one decimal space as listed.

However, for the third if statement it does the exact same thing but checks that the "myint" variable is an int type and when the float variable is called, it has more decimal points.

```
String: hello + test
Hi Matthew Float value: 10.0
Float value is 10.000000 & Integer value is 20
```

I found out that `print(['Float value is', myfloat] + ['& Integer value is', myint])` when run shows `['Float value is', 10.0, '& Integer value is', 20]` so my initial guess is because of the %f token.

Is there something that I'm writing wrong in the code? Would appreciate your help on this one.

Comment: `%f` allows you to specify the number of decimal places to print. If you don't do this, it defaults to 6.

Comment: E.g. `%.2f` will print 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `%f` to `%s` to make it behave similarly as in interpreter mode, i.e. the number of decimal places is dynamic.

```py
print('Float value is %s & Integer value is' % myfloat, myint)
> Float value is 10.0 & Integer value is 20
```

Also, if you are on Python 3.6 or newer consider using f-strings, they are more user-friendly:

```py
print(f'Float value is {myfloat} & Integer value is {myint}')
> Float value is 10.0 & Integer value is 20
```

You can also easily control the number of decimal places with `:.Xf` syntax (you can do the same with `%f` as mentioned in comments under your question):

```py
print(f'Float value is {myfloat:.3f} & Integer value is {myint}')
> Float value is 10.000 & Integer value is 20
```

BTW, you don't need to use `float()` when declaring a float variable:

```py
myfloat = float(10.0)
```

Python knows this automatically because it sees that the number contains `.`. It can be useful to make a floating point number from an integer, though:

```py
myfloat = float(10)
```